# Open Amazon EC2 instance ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redhat, iptables

I have been trying to open ports for a server program and have had no luck with the process.

I am using Redhat linux and have created and applied a security group for the ports 22, 3306, 5500 from the address 0.0.0.0:0.

When running nmap on the server address it reports the ports 22 and 111 are both open and when checking the port 5500 directly it reports filtered instead of open.

I have tried accepting the port directly within iptables as well as stoping iptables but no luck with either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you need me to run any extra commands to help understand the issue please let me know. I have searched through other topics for solutions and have tried their answers with no luck. So please let know what I can do for you before down voting my question with no given reason.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running anything on port 5500?  Can you run on the instance ?

```
lsof -i:5500
```

If nothing returns you don't have anything running on 5500.

If you are running something there, what is it ? It's possible that whatever is running on 5500 is filtered by the app. For example if you are running a web server it could be bound to 127.0.0.1 or localhost instead of 0.0.0.0

Hope it helps.

Comment: after running the command I receive no output,  I guess that is not the issue.